# How to percentage and count in SSRS Pie Chart

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, pie-chart

I have a Pie chart generated using SSRS. I would like to Show both Count and percentage in the Pie chart.

Right now, I am able yo show the count in pie charts as well as in the report.

I want to show the name of the partition and also the percentage directly pointed out.

Example :

ALD 38% 56

please help me withe properties to do it.

I'm using VS 2008

Answer (score 10, accepted):

write down an expression on series label data like -

```
=Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "Chart1_SeriesGroup1") & "("  
    &  Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "Chart1_SeriesGroup1")  * 100 /Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "DataSet1") 
    & "%)"
```

Here Chart1_SeriesGroup1 is the group name if you look at series group setting

[image]

Here DataSet1 is the name of Dataset

Here is the final output

[image]

Cheers :-)

Comment: Is there a way to set the percentage's decimal spaces to a maximum of 2.

Comment: try this in expression =Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "Chart1_SeriesGroup1") & "("  &  Format(Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "Chart1_SeriesGroup1")  * 100 /Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "DataSet1"),"#0.00") & "%)"

Comment: Great.! Thanks I want the percentages of pie chart to be displayed in the Chart as the image you have shown. But that information is being displayed on Legend. I want to hide legend ans show name count and percentage on the chart itself, Like Sales 120 (60% )My last question for the day..

Comment: sorry, i did not get exactly, i think you mean to display series name along with value .. try this =Fields!Series.Value & " " &  Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "Chart1_SeriesGroup1") & "("  &  Format(Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "Chart1_SeriesGroup1")  * 100 /Sum(Fields!DATA.Value, "DataSet1"),"#0.00") & "%)"

Comment: just right click on series & choose option "series group properties " & then write same expression (sent above) in label

Comment: Thank You. I wrote the same expression on Series Label Properties. It worked.

Answer (score 20):

1-right click on chart and select "show data label"

[image]

2-right click on label an select "series label properties"

[image]

3- general -> label data -> set this value = "#PERCENT (#VALY)"
[image]

4- it will be like this screenshot

[image]

Comment: This should be the top answer.

Comment: More information on the key words available to us in charts here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/chart-legend-change-item-text-report-builder

Answer (score 1):

In the label Properties type "#PERCENT" in Label Data

This can be used on its own or in conjunction with the other value itself by adding "#PERCENT(#VALY)"

Place this in quotes if you are trying to concat other values with it. For instance, this would show the label with the accompanying percent below

`=First(Fields!Data.Value, "Chart_Group") & vbcrlf & "#PERCENT"`

Where "Chart_Group" is the name of the grouped on field